# Actionscript 3.0 - Trying to remove a child

Tags: actionscript

Simple simple problem but I can't get it to work.
So I just have a class with a display object, a ball. I create instances of it from Main.as
and run a for loop to check if I hit the ball and if I do, I want to remove the object.
But I can't.

What's wrong with my code?

---

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;


    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var clay:Clay;
        private var clayCollection:Vector.<Clay> = new Vector.<Clay>;
        private var crash:Crash;
        private var crashCollection:Vector.<Crash> = new Vector.<Crash>;
        private var timer:Timer = new Timer(0);
        private var newClayTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

        public function Main()
        {
            newClayTimer.start();
            newClayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addNewClay);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkForHit);
        }

        private function checkForHit(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (clayCollection.length > 0)
            {
              for (var i:int = 0; i < clayCollection.length; i++) 
              {
                if (e.target.hitTestObject(clayCollection[i]))
                {
                    clayCollection.splice(i, 1);
                    removeChild(clayCollection[i]);
                }
              }
            }
        }

        private function addNewClay(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            clay = new Clay();
            addChild(clay);
            clayCollection.push(clay);  
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a break point in the hit test code block, does it trigger?  If so, what happens if you move the splice line of code after the removeChild line of code (so that the object you want to remove is still at the index in the collection)?  Also, wouldn't it be simpler to just add a click listener on each "clay" object?  Then you'd KNOW which one was clicked, because it would be the currentTarget of the event.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to change position with the splice and the removechild but it gives me the same object reference error.   I don't know if putting a listener on each object would do anything other than adding code and cpu power.

Comment: It will be less cpu usage if you're only firing a listener when an object you care about, rather than any object.  It wouldn't add any code...you'd simply move the addEventListener code into addNewClay, but it would only be one line (referring to the new Clay instead of the stage).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < clayCollection.length; i++)  {
   var clay:Clay = clayCollection[i];
   if (e.target.hitTextObject) {
      //seems to me all clays will hit test as true with the stage?
      removeChild(clay);
      clayCollection.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

That way you know that the object that you're trying to remove is definitely the one that hit tested true.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Amy, listen for a click on the instance of clay, not the stage. You can still remove it from your array, something like this (untested code):

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;


public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var clay:Clay;
    private var clayCollection:Vector.<Clay> = new Vector.<Clay>;
    private var crash:Crash;
    private var crashCollection:Vector.<Crash> = new Vector.<Crash>;
    private var timer:Timer = new Timer(0);
    private var newClayTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

    public function Main()
    {
        newClayTimer.start();
        newClayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addNewClay);


    }

    private function checkForHit(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // identify the target as Clay
        var clay:Clay = e.target as Clay;
        if(contains(clay)) removeChild(clay);

        // remove it from your array
        for each (var c:Clay in clayCollection) {
             if (c == clay) clayCollection.splice(clayCollection.indexOf(c), 1);
        }


    }

    private function addNewClay(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        clay = new Clay();
        clay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkForHit);
        addChild(clay);
        clayCollection.push(clay);  
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the program created a instance of the object and you mouse click it, the debugger threw this error.

Main Thread (Suspended: RangeError: Error #1125: The index 0 is out of range 0.)
        Main/checkForHit

The fix is that you need to delimit the index of the loop as you slice it. Also the sequence of when you apply the splice and delimit is important.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;


public class Main extends Sprite {
    private var clay:Clay;
    private var clayCollection:Vector.<Clay> = new Vector.<Clay>;
    private var timer:Timer = new Timer(0);
    private var newClayTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

    public function Main(){
        newClayTimer.start();
        newClayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addNewClay);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkForHit);

    }//END MAIN()

    private function checkForHit(e:MouseEvent):void{

        if (clayCollection.length > 0)
        {
          for (var i:int = 0; i != clayCollection.length; i++) 
          {
            trace(i,clayCollection.length);
            if (e.target.hitTestObject(clayCollection[i]))
            {
               removeChild(clayCollection[i]);
                clayCollection.splice(i, 1);
               i--;
            } 
          }
        }
    }//END checkForHit()

    private function addNewClay(e:TimerEvent):void{
            clay = new Clay();
            addChild(clay);
            clayCollection.push(clay);
    }//END addNewClay()

}//END MAINCLASS

}//END PACKAGE
```